# Open a sub window with link?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I'm using Vaadin7, and I looking for how to open a sub-window using link.

I'm trying this, but not work.

> public class MyWindow extends Window{
>
> ```
>   public MyWindow(){
>      super("MyWindow");
>      center();
>      setModal(true);
>      setClosable(false);
>     setDraggable(false);
>     setResizable(false);
>  }
> ```
>
> }
>
> public class OpenMyWindow extends Window{
>        private Link link;
>
> ```
>  public MyWindow(){
>     super("OpenMyWindow");
>     center();
>     setModal(true);
>     setClosable(false);
>     setDraggable(false);
>     setResizable(false);
>
>      link = new Link("Open Window", new ExternalResource("MyWindow");
>      VerticalLayout v = new VerticalLayout();
>       setContent(v);
>       v.addComponent(link);
>  }
> ```
>
> }

Any idea how to do work ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a link for opening a sub window. Use a button instead. If it has to look like a link, then you can style the button as a link.

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me!");
button.setStyleName(Button.STYLE_LINK);
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // open your sub window here
        Window sub = new Window("Subwindow");
        v.addWindow(sub);
    }
});

v.addComponent(button);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, I make this: button.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK); and works. Now, are you knows how to open a Window over another Window ? I'm trying this: new MyWindow().setVisible(true); , but doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code above. You have to create the new SubWindow and add it as component to your view. You can also set the width of it with `sub.setWidth("123px")`.